# AspNetCore MVC - ControllerBase.Challenge Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, .net-4.6.1

Trying to use [Challenge(AuthenticationProperties, String[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.challenge?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Challenge_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticationProperties_System_String___) as below in my mvc project

```
 [Authorize]
 public IActionResult SignIn()
 {
     return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
 }
```

But getting following error

> cannot convert from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties  to string

Am I doing something wrong here?

Updated

[image]

Comment: It thinks you are trying to call [`Challenge(String[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.challenge?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Challenge_System_String___)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue

It was the reference to `AuthenticationProperties`

This come from both `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication`

It was pointing to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication` which caused the issue